# Event for saving Custom Fields data? Or before save

Tags: custom-field, plugin-events

I am looking for the event is triggered when saves or just before the com_fields custom field saves the data?

Also, is there any where I can find the list of all com_fields event trigger the ones I found on Joomla's issue tracker are

- onCustomFieldsGetTypes
- onCustomFieldsPrepareField
- onCustomFieldsPrepareDom

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `onContentBeforeSave` and the `onContentAfterSave` event and filter your functions with the proper `$context` for the `com_fields`, so it will run only when you are in `com_fields`.

Answer (score 1):

A list of all the events specific to the fields:

- `onCustomFieldsBeforePrepareField`
- `onCustomFieldsPrepareField`
- `onCustomFieldsAfterPrepareField`
- `onCustomFieldsPrepareDom`
- `onCustomFieldsGetTypes`

Since the fields component does not have its own specific "Before Save" and "After Save" events, then the `onContentBeforeSave` and the `onContentAfterSave` events will be triggered before and after saving the field (please check the `save` function in the `libraries/legacy/model/admin.php` file as well as the constructor in that same file).